# Pass value of javascript variable into flask python

Tags: javascript, python, flask

`logReg = (Math.exp(ptsCrunch) / (1 + Math.exp(ptsCrunch)) * 100)`

The code above is a javascript variable that I want to pass into an if-else statement in flask. I have used ajax and various @app.route requests but none seems to work. Please help!

Comment: use JSONResponse in return statement

Comment: Add your ajax code with some error.

Answer (score 0):

This sample code will help you.

**Flask:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask import jsonify

from flask_cors import CORS,cross_origin
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, support_credentials=True)


@app.route("/send", methods=['GET'])
@cross_origin()
def post_bot_response():

    usr_inp = request.args.get('msg');

    ### res = chat(urs_inp)
    return 'd' ## return res


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=8009)

## For deploying the app use `app.run(debug=False, host="0.0.0.0", port=80)
```

**Html:**

```
<div>
<div id="chatBox">
<p class="botText"><span>Hi! I'm a chatbot, how can I help you today?</span></p>
</div>

<!-- <form action="" method="POST"> -->
<input id="textInput" type="text" name="msg" placeholder="Message"/>
<input type="submit" value="Send"/>
<!-- </form> -->
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function getBotResponse() {
var rawText = $("#textInput").val();
var userHtml = '<p class="userText"><span>' + rawText + "</span></p>";
$("#textInput").val("");
$("#chatBox").append(userHtml);
document
.getElementById("textInput")
.scrollIntoView({ block: "start", behavior: "smooth" });
$.get("http://127.0.0.1:8009/send", { msg: rawText }).done(function(data) {
var botHtml = '<p class="botText"><span>' + data + "</span></p>";
$("#chatBox").append(botHtml);
document.getElementById("textInput")
.scrollIntoView({ block: "start", behavior: "smooth" });
});

}
$("#textInput").keypress(function(e) {
if (e.which == 13) {
  getBotResponse();

}
console.log("works");
});


</script>
```